# How to get network and disk usage per process

Tags: monitoring

How to get **network** and **disk usage** and ram and cpu utilization **per process** in simple command?

Answer (score 2):

Display current processes or threads during IO

```
iotop - -only -b -n1
```

List top 10 CPU-consuming processes

```
ps axo %cpu,command | sort -nr | head
```

List top 10 memory-consuming processes

```
ps ago %mem,command | sort -nr | head
```

List connections per processes

```
netstat -plant #for tcp
netstat -planu #for udp
```

Network usage per remotes with `iftop`